# Is it possible to map a keyboard shortcut to open an Explorer window to the path of a file or folder selected in the Project view in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, keymapping

Is it possible to map a keyboard shortcut to open an Explorer window to the path of a file or folder selected in the Project view in IntelliJ? I'm hoping there is (or I can create) a shortcut to immediately open an Explorer window showing the path of a file or folder selected in the "Project" view of IntelliJ.

I've looked around the options in the Keymap section of IntelliJ's Settings, but I couldn't find anything related to this particular function.

[image: IntelliJ context menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this: File > Settings > Keymap > Other > Show in File Manager

Comment: Perfect, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

For now I remapped Path Popup to an easier key combination, I was just hoping to skip the extra step and open Explorer directly with a keymap.